# How to detect the collision between CCArmature class' child and CCSprite class' child in Cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x

I want to know how to detect the collision between **CCArmature** class' child and **CCSprite** class' child?

Do you have any instructions or samples or even ideas? Please share with me.

I read the sample but it's just the instruction to detect the collision between 2 sprites.

Thanks

Comment: what are you refering to, a tutorial or template project? Show us relevent parts of your code and add more context to your question please.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D: I need some ideas because the sprite is stable while armature can move and the shape isn't stable, but I want to detect collision exactly. I don't know where I can begin